# Get YouTube video title with video ID in PHP

Tags: php, video, youtube-api

I have to get the YouTube video title with the YouTube video ID in PHP.

Currently I am doing it like this:

```
    $html = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" . $video_id;
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTMLFile($html);
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $title_div = $doc->getElementById('eow-title');
    $title = $title_div->nodeValue;
```

But this is throwing an error as:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMpCsfvi_3c): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 429 Too Many Requests in /home/vhosts/xxxx/xxxx/get_youtube_title.php on line 6

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMpCsfvi_3c" in /home/vhosts/xxxx/xxxx/get_youtube_title.php on line 6
```

The above method works fine on [GoDaddy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GoDaddy) hosting, but not on 101domain.com hosting.

Another method I have tried is this:

```
if($content = file_get_contents("http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=" . $video_id)) {
    parse_str($content, $ytarr);
    $myvideos[$i]['video_title'] = $ytarr['title'];
}
else
    $myvideos[$i]['video_title'] = "No title";
```

This throws an error as:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=hMpCsfvi_3c): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 402 Payment Required in /home/vhosts/xxxx/get_youtube_title.php on line 6

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=hMpCsfvi_3c" in /home/vhosts/xxxx/get_youtube_title.php on line 6
```

The last method I tried was this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://youtube.com/get_video_info? video_id=" . $video_id);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

This doesn't throw any error, but it doesn't work either. The error reporting is `E_ALL` and `display_errors` is set to 1.

Somebody has told me it's safer to use the YouTube API for this. Since I am new to YouTube API, I need some help.

How can I get the video title with the video ID in PHP? Also an
easy-to-follow tutorial for the YouTube API.

<sub>Note: **This is not duplicate question**.</sub>

<sub>Other answers on Stack Overflow about the YouTube API are pre 2013, and they no longer work.</sub>

Comment: answer to the "easy to follow tutorial" part - https://github.com/madcoda/php-youtube-api/wiki/started-with-php-composer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the YouTube API v3 and the list method, sending in the ID as a parameter and you will get information about that specific video, *https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#id*.

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos

With the id parameter

> ```
> string
> ```

The id parameter specifies a comma-separated list of the YouTube video ID(s) for the resource(s) that are being retrieved. In a video resource, the id property specifies the video's ID.

In your case, with the PHP SDK, the example would be something like:

```
# Call the videos.list method to retrieve location details for each video.
$videosResponse = $youtube->videos->listVideos('snippet, recordingDetails', array(
'id' => $videoIds,
));
```

Comment: @Slowmove I got it working another way, but your answer helped me a lot to reach that solution. Thanks for your efforts. :) May God bless you!!

Answer (score 8):

I got it working with `file_get_contents()`, but I used a different URL this time.

The URL I used was:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=' . $video_id . '&key=' . $YoutubeAPIKey . '&part=snippet
```

For example:

```
function get_youtube_title($video_id){
    $html = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=' . $video_id . '&key=alskdfhwueoriwaksjdfnzxcvxzfserwesfasdfs&part=snippet';
    $response = file_get_contents($html);
    $decoded = json_decode($response, true);
    foreach ($decoded['items'] as $items) {
         $title = $items['snippet']['title'];
         return $title;
    }
}
echo $title = get_youtube_title('PQqudiUdGuo');
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is a single line of code I created:

```
echo explode('</title>', explode('<title>', file_get_contents("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VideoIDHERE"))[1])[0];
```

Comment: **bonus - if you want left side of Youtube 1 row titel code (use this one):** `echo explode(' - YouTube',explode('</title>',explode('<title>',file_get_contents("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VideoIDHERE"))[1])[0])[0];`

Comment: An explanation would be in order. What is the idea? How does it work? What does it do? Why does it use an `echo`?

Comment: It is fine, but how to remove "- YouTube" from the title? It appears for every title.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
$video_id = ...;
$url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" . $video_id;

$page = file_get_contents($url);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($page);

$title_div = $doc->getElementById('eow-title');
$title = $title_div->nodeValue;

var_dump($title);
exit;
```

And also this worked (which is essentially identical to your first method):

```
$url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" . $video_id;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

$title_div = $doc->getElementById('eow-title');
$title = $title_div->nodeValue;

var_dump($title);
exit;
```

So I'm thinking your issues are related to something other than your code.

Answer (score 5):

```
function get_youtube($url){

    $youtube = "http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=" . $url . "&format=json";
    $curl = curl_init($youtube);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $return = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return json_decode($return, true);
}

$url = // YouTube video URL

// Display Data
print_r(get_youtube($url));
```

Comment: returns SSL is required

Comment: You can just `file_get_contents` this data if `allow_url_fopen` is `1`

Answer (score 1):

I tried the previous solutions without PHP SDK and they were not working for me. If I try file_get_contents, I get an error from the API.

I checked the YouTube API v3 and for now (2019) this solution works for me. You´ll need your own YouTube API key (or global API key) from [Google Cloud Platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Cloud_Platform). After replacing "yourAPIkey" in the example:

```
function get_youtube_title($video_id){
  $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=' . $video_id . '&key=yourAPIkey';
  $curl = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $data = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);
  $decoded = json_decode($data, true);
  foreach ($decoded['items'] as $items) {
     $title= $items['snippet']['title'];
     return $title;
  }
}
echo $title = get_youtube_title('fhntQrZsjdw');
```

If you´re sending a request from HTTPS, this will work. From HTTP or an unsecure localhost put one more line **before curl_exec**:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$video_info = file_get_contents('https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=' . $video_id);
parse_str($video_info, $video_info_array);
$title = json_decode($video_info_array['player_response'])->videoDetails->title;
```

Comment: $video_info = file_get_contents('https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=' . end($video_formulate));
        parse_str($video_info, $video_info_array);
        $title = json_decode($video_info_array['player_response']);
print_r($title->videoDetails->title);
exit;

Answer (score 0):

FOR Youtube:
With this code you get the title of a video without needing APIkey

```html
$id_video='1OlEupMZQyo';// <---id_video example
echo $title = get_title_youtube($id_video);

function get_title_youtube($id_video){
$code_html = html_entity_decode( file_get_contents("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=".$id_video) );
$search_string_title = '"title":{"runs":[{"text":"';
$found_string = strpos_recursive($code_html, $search_string_title);
if($found_string) {
    foreach($found_string as $string_position ) {
        $string_title = substr($code_html, $string_position+26, 100); 
        $title = explode('"', $string_title);
        $title=$title[0];
        break;
    }   
} 
return $title;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

**PHP snippet**

```
function getTubeTitel($id)
{
    $tmp = file_get_contents("http://youtube.com/watch?v=" . $id);

    $tmp2 = substr($tmp, (strpos($tmp, "<title>") + 7), 220);

    $tmp = substr($tmp2, 0, strpos($tmp2, "</title>") - 9);

    echo htmlspecialchars_decode($tmp);
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. What is the idea? How does it work? What does it do? Why does it use an `echo`?